# CheckBox Style in Android?

Tags: android

I want to do make my check box small than the actual size. How to do it? Any Idea?

for Example we can set the button as small size using the attribute

```
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
```

ThanX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the size of those components through the usage of: android:layout_width and android:layout_height

You might want to check [DroidDraw Widget Guide](http://www.droiddraw.org/widgetguide.htm) for reference.
Also, they have the DroidDraw GUI Editor available through that same link.